# How to get values of *ngFor in same line

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

`<div *ngFor = "let val of values">{{val}} </div>`

There are 3 values in values array. Each val is printing in different line. I want all 3 vals in the same line. How to do it?? Please help!!

Edit: even using span is giving the output in 3 lines

Comment: You're creating div's for each value and div's naturally have `display: block`, which aligns them under each other. You could use span's instead.

Comment: Even span is giving the output in 3 lines @MikeS.

Comment: [It definitely works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4luzyg?file=src/app/app.component.html) :) Please try to reproduce your behavior inside of a stackblitz or similiar, so people can take a look

Answer (score 1):

use span

```
<span *ngFor = "let val of values">{{val}} </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's caused by the fact that you are using the ngFor loop in a div, which is a block element. Block elements start with a new line. You can put ngFor on a line element like button, or you can change display to inline in styles.

```
<button *ngFor = "let val of values">{{val}} </button>
```

or

```
div {display: inline}
```

Try it

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using the ngFor loop in a div, which is a block element. Block elements start with a new line. You can change the display to inline-block in styles.